# Angular component not get called

Tags: angular, angular-router

I just started angular project. I created new component `universal-table.component` with just 2 prints to console, but it seems that this component is not get called. HTML is not loaded in browser when I go to the `http://localhost:4200/model` nor browser log filled, but I can see `UniversalTableComponent_Host.ngfactory.js` in Firefox's "debug" tab.

### Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {UniversalTable} from "./universal-table.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-universal-table',
  templateUrl: './universal-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./universal-table.component.css']
})
export class UniversalTableComponent implements OnInit {
  private model: UniversalTable;

  // public universalTable: Field = new Field();

  constructor() {
    console.log("1");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("2");
  }
}
```

### Router:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalTableComponent } from './universal-table/universal-table.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'model', component: UniversalTableComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: How do you create your component?

Comment: I mean if you used the command: ng g c "path" , you will get the necessary element to create your component. You can get more information via this link :https://angular.io/cli/generate

Answer (score 0):

in app.component.html you must add:

```
<app-universal-table></app-universal-table>
```

This is invoking root element.

Answer (score 0):

In your **app.component.html** you should put

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

This is where your component will be rendered.